# Xamarin iOS "Can't resolve the reference 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`" when linking

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, signals

I am getting the following error when linking my Xamarin iOS application:

```
MTOUCH : error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<System.Byte> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HandshakeProtocol::SuccessHandshakeData', referenced from the method 'System.Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext/<WriteHandshakeResponseAsync>d__50::MoveNext()' in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1?view=net-7.0), System.ReadOnlyMemory is in System.Runtime.dll so I've tried adding `--linkskip System.Runtime` to the 'Additional mtouch arguments' and `[assembly: Preserve(typeof(System.ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>), AllMembers = true)]` to Application.Main.  Neither had any effect.

I've also tried adding a code to reference `System.ReadOnlyMemory<Byte>` in `Application.Main`.

I've tried cleaning, deleting all obj/ and bin/ folders, and rebuilding.

The application compiles and works fine if I use "Don't Link" but I have to use "Link Framework SDKs Only" in order to deploy to the AppStore.

EDIT: I believe I misread the error message originally.  I see now the reference error is for Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HandshakeProtocol
(which is a field of type System.ReadOnlyMemory).  So I've tried adding `--linkskip Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol` and `[assembly: Preserve(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.HandshakeProtocol), AllMembers = true)]` neither of which had any effect.

**EDIT 2**: I believe I have narrowed down the problem to this:

The project includes references to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.

The only package available for Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR is version 1.1.0 which includes a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common 1.1.0.

The project references Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 5.0.8 which includes a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common 5.0.8.

Apparently there was a breaking change in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common between 1.1.0 and 5.0.8.

I *assume* MTOUCH only keeps one version of a library and hence that creates the problem I am seeing.

I am exploring my options.

Comment: you are looking at the .NET 7 docs.  Xamarin.iOS doesn't appear to support that class

Comment: @Jason What do you mean "Xamarin.iOS doesn't appear to support that class"? Note that the application compiles and works fine on iOS if I use "Don't Link".

Comment: that's what the docs say.  Is this code in the iOS project, or a library?

Comment: @Jason Could you provide a link to the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: follow the link in your post and select Xamarin iOS from the dropdown

Comment: FYI: Confirming [ASP.NET Core 7 signalR is supported on Xamarin.iOS 11.14.0.4 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#net-client). I did not look for the specific call, but if it works with no linking, then it shouldn't be specific to the call - perhaps that was just the first linked reference to SignalR. Sounds like something else needs to be excluded from linking. I don't know what.

Comment: Actually, I see what Jason saw. `HandshakeProtocol::SuccessHandshakeData` does not exist in Core 7. Last mentioned in Core 2.2. Maybe two different nugets are referring to two different versions of SignalR? And linking "resolves" differently when no link? Its as if it takes `SignalR.Common` from one version, but attempts to link to `SignalR.Protocol` of a different version. Look at other packages, see which reference `SignalR` or `SignalR.Protocol`. Also skip link `SignalR.Common`.

Comment: I believe you are correct @ToolmakerSteve.  I've updated the question with further details that seem to suggest this is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a conflict between two versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.  I can only assume when not linking both versions are included but when linking only the most recent is included.

In my case I was able to move the conflicting reference to another assembly that isn't used by the mobile app and that solved the problem.

Thanks to the comments from Jason and ToolmakerSteve for putting me on the path to a solution!